# select from missing table error in subquery (after WHEN EXISTS in CASE)

Tags: sql, sql-server

** *edited to invert logic in EXISTS test*

I need to select a field from a table that may not exist. I also need to do this in a sub query.

There is a code release coming from engineering that will add a table to a database I scrape for reporting. If the table exists, select the field. If it does not, give a generic failure.

** Yes, there are tons of examples on how to use EXISTS. This goes outside of those as it deals with something that may not exist.

The new code release will rollout to several sites, some may not have the table immediately where others will. My stuff has to ready for Day Zero - aka: rolled out before hand (day -1?).

Here is my code (tables and columns renamed) that I am trying to make work in SQL Server Management Studio (SQL 2016) (SSMS 17.4)

```
select 'Cern' as  SiteName, 
(
select 
case when exists (select 1 from sys.tables where name like 'ProtonAcceleratorSecurity')
 then
   (select top 1 isnull(SecurityID,'Not on file') from [ProtonAcceleratorSecurity] with (nolock) )  
 else
   (select 'No Security Table Found')
end  
 as SecurityID
```

It looks contrived, but it is very near what I am trying to do, using that exact query (but nothing to do with security...)

The goal is to get back the site name, and the first security ID (at random - doesn't matter - no consistency required) - but only if the table actually exists.

The problem is that SSMS throws an error telling me that the table is an invalid object which I already know.

### "Invalid object name 'ProtonAcceleratorSecurity' "

Final answer from @TabAlleman, with a minor correction:

````
SET @sql = '
select ''Cern'' as  SiteName, ' +
( select 
    case when exists (select 1 from sys.tables where name like 'ProtonAcceleratorSecurity')
 then
   '(select top 1 isnull(SecurityID,''Not on file'') from [ProtonAcceleratorSecurity] with (nolock) )'
 else
   '''No Security Table Found'''
end  ) 
+ ' as SecurityID ';

EXEC (@sql); ```
````

Comment: The code has to be able to compile to a single execution plan before it starts running.  If part of the code refers to a table that doesn't exist, it can't compile and can't run.  A standard approach is two take it in two steps; code that creates code - Dynamic SQL.  You check if the table exists, based on that create a string containing the SQL you actually want to run, then use `sp_executesql` to execute that dynamically generate sql string.  The call to `sp_executesql` causes a 2nd execution plan to be compiled and executed, and at no point does any code ever refer to the "missing" table.

Comment: Thanks @MatBailie - makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your error is that SQL Server will parse and compile your entire statement before it executes it.  So your query cannot contain references to invalid objects, even though the query itself checks to make sure the object is valid before referencing it.   The parser isn't smart enough to know that the subquery will not be called if the object doesn't exist, so it will prevent you from running the query at all.

One way you can trick the parser is through dynamic sql, which doesn't get pre-parsed:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max);

SET @sql = '
select ''Cern'' as  SiteName, '

+
select 
case when exists (select 1 from sys.tables where name like 'ProtonAcceleratorSecurity')
 then
   '(select top 1 isnull(SecurityID,''Not on file'') from [ProtonAcceleratorSecurity] with (nolock) )'
 else
   '''No Security Table Found'''
end  
+

' as SecurityID 
';

EXEC (@sql);
```

EDIT because I'm not testing as I go, but just to make the idea clear:

You need to check for the existence of the table in the outer query, but then only construct a dynamic query that uses the table if it exists. To make it really simple, ignoring your original CASE structure, you want to logically do this:

```
IF EXISTS({SELECT query to test for MyTable})
  @SQL = 'query that references MyTable';
ELSE
  @SQL = 'query that doesn't reference MyTable';

EXECUTE (@SQL);
```

PS:  I think I just fixed the syntax in my first example.

Comment: That example breaks because of how you formed it. As I would write it, it would go as:   ``` DECLARE @sql varchar(max);

SET @sql = ' select ''Cern'' as  SiteName, '
+
'( select 
case when exists (select 1 from sys.tables where name like ''ProtonAcceleratorSecurity'')
 then
  (select top 1 isnull(SecurityID,''Not on file'') from [ProtonAcceleratorSecurity] with (nolock) )
 else
   ''No Security Table Found''
end   as SecurityID ';

EXEC (@sql); ```

Comment: It could be poorly formed, as I didn't test the code myself, but it should give the basic idea.

Comment: It's a great idea, but still gets evaluated. Hmmmm

Comment: It would only get evaluated if you have a reference to the table-that-might-not-exist in the outer query.   As long as that reference only exists in the dynamic context, it should not get evaluated by the parser.

Comment: ** Fixed missing end parenthesis ** As I would write it, it would go as:   ``` DECLARE @sql varchar(max);

SET @sql = ' select ''Cern'' as  SiteName, '
+
'( select 
case when exists (select 1 from sys.tables where name like ''ProtonAcceleratorSecurity'')
 then
  (select top 1 isnull(SecurityID,''Not on file'') from [ProtonAcceleratorSecurity] with (nolock) )
 else
   ''No Security Table Found''
end   as SecurityID )';

EXEC (@sql); ```

Comment: The problem with that is that you are still checking for the existence of the table in the same context as you are querying it.   See my edit.

Comment: Ah.. Small syntax issue - but it works as desired. (I will post my edits here)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to do this in a single query.  One suggestion is to hide this in a view:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('ProtonAcceleratorSecurity') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE VIEW ProtonAcceleratorSecurity
        SELECT 'Not on file' as SecurityID
END;
```

Then your query can work simply as:

```
select 'Cern' as SiteName, 
       (select top 1 coalesce(SecurityID, 'Not on file')
        from ProtonAcceleratorSecurity 
       ) as SecurityID
```

Comment: Since this view is intended to stand in for the missing object up until a table of that name is deployed, wouldn't this become an issue when the real table is deployed if it has the exact same name?

Comment: @thermos The deployment of the real table would need to drop the view, or be deployed to a different schema (with care taken to ensure which object takes precedence in different contexts).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the problem because the table must exist when **the statement** is executed.

If you divide it into two statements then there is no problem. The one referencing the non existent table is marked for deferred compilation and as it is never executed the full compilation is never needed and no error.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('ProtonAcceleratorSecurity', 'U') IS NULL
  SELECT 'Cern'                    AS SiteName,
         'No Security Table Found' AS SecurityID 
ELSE
  SELECT TOP 1 'Cern' AS SiteName,
               isnull(SecurityID, 'Not on file') AS SecurityID 
  FROM   [ProtonAcceleratorSecurity] WITH (nolock)
  ORDER BY ....
```